# Presence/absence of topologically protected edge states on the boundary of two topological insulators

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

A normal insulator is the same as vacuum because one can change the band structure from one to another without closing the gap, but for topological insulators (talking about 2D TI) like 1T'-[TMDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal_dichalcogenide_monolayers) or HgTe/CdTe, there is a band closing and reopening process due to SOC making the topological have a nonzero/nontrivial topological number. To make the question simple we only consider $Z_2$ invariant and a 2D topological insulator would have $Z_2=1$ and a normal insulator would have $Z_2=0$.

And topological insulators have a bulk-boundary correspondence making the edge states of TI topologically protected. However, the edge states of a normal insulator which still exist due to the broken translation symmetry are not protected.

My question is, can we say that to have topologically protected edge states, one must have two insulators with different $Z_2$ numbers like 0 and 1 or a TI and vacuum? As for the normal insulators' edge states are not protected because we are talking about it having vacuum outside which shares its topological number 0. And the topological protected edge states will be absent when two TI having $Z_2=1$ are put together, even if the two are different materials.

This would certainly answer the extreme situation when a huge bulk of topological are presented and it is insulating in the bulk and there are no topological protected conducting edge states. But I can treat a huge bulk of TI as two TI with the same topological number put together and the topological edge states vanish because both sides are topologically the same.

If not so, please leave detailed illustrations and references, if so do you find any experiments supporting the above understanding?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?